# Flutter Retrieve Value from TextField

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get the value from the TextField then compare it to a string = '123'

If the value = '123' then alert 'Successful!' or else alert 'Failed!'

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Retrieve Text Input',
      home: MyCustomForm(),
    );
  }
}
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyCustomFormState createState() => _MyCustomFormState();
}
class _MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  TextEditingController myController = new TextEditingController();
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Retrieve Text Input'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: TextField(
          controller: myController,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if(myController == '123')
          {
            showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                content: Text('Successful!'),
              );
            },
            );
          }
          else
          {
            showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                content: Text('Failed!'),
              );
            },
          );
          }
      
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.text_fields),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My code always shows failed even I entered '123'. Can someone help me to figure out what I did wrong here? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the text inside a TextField Controller, you need to use myController.text, the myController is just a controller itself so you can't compare it to a String like that.

So, you should change this line

`if(myController == '123')`

into this

`if(myController.text == '123')`